# How to handle hierarchical queries in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

How do you handle hierarchical queries and the display of their data in ASP.NET MVC?

Lets say I have some Model, that looks like this:
(with additional properties)

```
public class Parent {
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ChildLvlOne> ChildsLvl1 {get; set;}
}

public class ChildLvlOne {
    public int ChildLvlOneId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<ChildLvlTwo> ChildsLvl2 {get; set;}
}

public class ChildLvlTwo {
    public int ChildLvlTwoId {get; set;}
    public ChildLvlOne ChildLvlOne {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<SomeOtherObject> SomeOtherObjects {get; set;} 
}
```

and now I want to display data from *Parent* combined with data from the children in both levels, but the data from *ChildLvlTwo* must be displayed in different ways depending on its related *SomeOtherObjects*.

So, my first idea was, to create a new ViewModel for *ChildLvlTwo* and add a property there, that determines which way it has to be displayed.
But to do this, I would have to create a new ViewModel for *ChildLvlOne* and *Parent* too and create a really huge select statement in the query.

Is there any good solution for problems like this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it matters how you want the data in the children displayed. Would something like this work:

```
from p in Parent
select new
{
    Parent = p,
    Child =  
    {
        ChildLvl1.ChildsLvl2.Select(l2 => ChildLv2.ChildLvlTwoId).ToList().Contains(1)  ? "Format1" :
        ChildLvl1.ChildsLvl2.Select(l2 => ChildLv2.ChildLvlTwoId).ToList().Contains(2) ? "Format2" :
        ChildLvl1.ChildsLvl2.Select(l2 => ChildLv2.ChildLvlTwoId).ToList().Contains(3) ? "Format3" : "Format4"
    }
};
```